# How to replace Detail in UISplitViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

Usually I can replace my detail view of splitview by this code in Objective-C:

```
  [self.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
  NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
  [viewControllerArray removeLastObject];

  [viewControllerArray addObject:self.detailViewController];
  [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO];
  [self.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

Try to rewrite it in Swift, but I even can't get the viewControllers in this code:

```
  NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
```

Swift:

```
    let test: UIViewController = (self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[1])!
```

It should have `test.viewControllers` , but it doesn't as seen in below pic

[image]

Does Swift handle the replace in splitview in different way?

Comment: There's no Swift code in your question. Update your question with your attempted Swift code. Explain what issues you are having with it.

Comment: Updated! Also with screenshot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me but I am not sure if this is the best practice:

```
    let detailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailNavigationViewController") as! UINavigationController
    self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] = detailViewController
```

Only need to get the desired viewController and assign it to index 1 of splitViewController

Comment: I keep a reference to the detail navigation controller from the storyboard  and set the array of new view controllers like you, i think it's more safe:
    detailNavController.setViewControllers([singleVC], animated: true)

Comment: It throws me an error "Fatal error: Index out of range".

Comment: it is probably not the best idear to access index of viewControllers directly
you should either use:
for classic split view controllers:
**showDetailViewController(destination, sender: self)**
or for the new colum-style Controllers:
**splitViewController?.setViewController(destination, for: .secondary)**